# xamarin forms Scrollview VerticalScrollBarVisibility does not visible for android only its working in IOS

Tags: visual-studio, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin-studio

I have tried Xamarin forms Scrollview VerticalScrollBarVisibility="always", but it does not visible for android,Its Showing in IOS devices.I need Scrollbar visible in android device also.Can anybody help me? Thank you in advance.
my Code:`<ScrollView   Orientation="Vertical" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Always"><Grid></Grid></ScrollView>`

Comment: IIRC, that's how Android works. I don't think Xamarin Forms can do anything about it ("Always" has no effect, because that's just how the Android scrollbar works) - scrollbar won't appear until user is touching the element.

Comment: You are Correct, when i touch a Screen scrollbar is visible in IOS device not showing in Android Devices, can you tell me how can i fix this issue?

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't reproduce this problem. When I touched the Screen and tried to move the UI, the scrollbar  is visible in android devices. I used the sample code [Xamarin.Forms - ScrollView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/userinterface-scrollviewdemos/) to test.

Comment: @Compassme - When you touch the screen, the scrollbar should appear on Android. If it does not, there must be additional code that you have not shown. (Actually, I'm not sure if the scrollbar will appear, if the view totally fits on the screen. Test with contents that extend beyond bottom of screen.)

Comment: thank you for you support, i have upgrade my xamarin.forms its working fine now.